# c# - listview does not add items when using a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, listview

Using a worker thread, I am adding items to a ListView, however to do this I have implemented a delegate in the form as shown below in the code sample.

**Problem:**

When the ListView.Items.add() line is executed, nothing is added to the ListView

**What I have tried:**

I added a button, when clicked, it successfully adds a ListViewItem to the ListView object, as it should. (this is before the worker thread start, for testing/debugging)

I have also tried swapping the ListView to a RichEdit in case I had a bug in the code, but the items successfully display in the RichEdit, thus I added another ListView incase the first/previous one was buggy, and without renaming the ListView, I tried adding the items, but without success.

**What happens in the Delegate:**

Nothing, after the clear() method, the 4 columns each with headers disappear and nothing is added to the list view

**Conclusion:**

My only conclusion is that the delegate is not compatible with the ListView, since I was able to add the items to a RichEdit, but not to a ListView.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

*code sample*

```
void connected_add_device()
        {
            string[] t = { "123", "-1", "sa.d.sdf.s.fg", "sda-f-sd-fgds-gf" };
            if (display_connected_Devices.InvokeRequired)
                display_connected_Devices.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    display_connected_Devices.Clear();
                    display_connected_Devices.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(t));
                }
                );
            else
            {
                display_connected_Devices.Clear();
                display_connected_Devices.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(t));
            }
        }
```

*For what it is worth, I had a bad GIT commit. After everthing is fixed, this ListView (which before the GIT issue, had successfuly displayed the items) now doesn't display the items anymore.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display_connected_Devices.Items.Clear();` instead. Because `display_connected_Devices.Clear();` will clear, like you noticed,  the columns aswell.

Comment: im sorry, so stupid of me, I had this in my original pre git-issue code, I can;t believe I overlooked this, thnx

Comment: No problem, you're not the first one making this mistake. There's a reason i noticed this this fast ;-)